# Self join next timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to merge timestamp from 2 different row based on Employee and punch card but the max or limit does not work with the from statement, if I only use > then i get every subsequent for everyday... I want the next higher value on a self join, also I have to mention that i have to use SQL 2008! so the lag and Lead does not work!

please help me.

```
 SELECT , Det.name
          ,Det.[time]
          ,Det2.[time]
          ,Det.[type]
          ,det2.type
          ,Det.[detail]

      FROM [detail] Det
      join [detail] Det2 on 
      Det2.name = Det.name

      and
      Det2.time > Det.time Max 1

    where det.type <>3

    Table detail
    NAME | Time | Type | detail
    john | 10:30|  1   | On 
    steve| 10:32|  1   | On 
    john | 10:34|  2   | break
    paul | 10:35|  1   | On 
    steve| 10:45|  3   | Off
    john | 10:49|  2   | on
    paul | 10:55|  3   | Off
    john | 11:12|  3   | Off
```

Wanted result

```
John | 10:30 | 10:34 | 1 | 2 | On 
John | 10:34 | 10:49 | 2 | 1 | Break
John | 10:49 | 11:12 | 1 | 3 | on
Steve| 10:32 | 10:45 | 1 | 3 | on
Paul | 10:35 | 10:55 | 1 | 3 | On
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there any primary key in the `detail` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with cross apply:

```
SELECT Det.name
      ,Det.[time]
      ,ca.[time]
      ,Det.[type]
      ,ca.type
      ,Det.[detail]
FROM [detail] Det
Cross Apply(Select Top 1 * From detail det2 where det.Name = det2.Name Order By det2.Time) ca
Where det.Type <> 3
```

Comment: Thank you i've ad to modify slightly but it gave me a good heads up! i had to add and det2.time< det.time in the cross apply :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said `LAG` or `LEAD` functions won't work for you, but you could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC)` on both tables and then do a `JOIN` on `RN1 = RN2 + 1`

This is just a idea, but I don't see an issue why it shouldn't work.

**Query:**

```
;WITH Data (NAME, TIME, type, detail)
AS (
    SELECT 'john', CAST('10:30' AS DATETIME2), 1, 'On'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'steve', '10:32', 1, 'On'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'john', '10:34', 2, 'break'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'paul', '10:35', 1, 'On'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'steve', '10:45', 3, 'Off'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'john', '10:49', 2, 'on'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'paul', '10:55', 3, 'Off'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'john', '11:12', 3, 'Off'
    )
SELECT t.NAME, LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), t.TIME, 100), 7)) AS time, LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), t2.TIME, 100), 7)) AS time, t.type, t2.type, t.detail
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY TIME) rn, *
    FROM Data
    ) AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY TIME) rn, *
    FROM Data
    ) AS t2
    ON t2.NAME = t.NAME
    AND t2.rn = t.rn + 1;
```

**Result:**

```
NAME    time    time    type    type    detail
----------------------------------------------
john    10:30AM 10:34AM 1       2       On
john    10:34AM 10:49AM 2       2       break
john    10:49AM 11:12AM 2       3       on
paul    10:35AM 10:55AM 1       3       On
steve   10:32AM 10:45AM 1       3       On
```

Any comments, concerns - let me know. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, the table actually include over a thousand employee that has about 50 different entries per day. do you have a way to achieve those results without manually enter each name?

Comment: Just use your own table `[detail]` instead of `Data`. I made CTE from your input data to see if query actually works. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @evaldas-buinauskas said,
The `OVER` and `LAG` statements in SQL will work for you.

Here is a similar example:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: unfortunatly, i can't use the lead and lag and over with sql 2008 :( but Giorgi gave me a good lead enought to find my answer thank you for your time!